# Using a constantly changing variable to define a list

Tags: python

I want to make a piece of code which pulls the title and link off an RSS feed and compiles it into a variable which can be then used in the message body. My problem is Body gets redefined every time i pull the info off the RSS. I am very new to programming and python, and I am under the impression that using a list would be the best thing to do.

```
for i in range(3):

    MessageTitle = feed['items'][i].title
    MessageLink = " - ",feed['items'][i]['link']

    Body = "%s%s%s%s" % (MessageTitle,"\n","\n", MessageLink) #in unicode

    gmail_user = "user@gmail.com"
    gmail_pwd = "pw"

    mail("user@gmail.com",
         "Reddit Update",
         Body)
```

I was going to insert the list below body, and use body to define it.. something like:

```
list[i] = [Body]
```

Am i on the right track?

Comment: You may want to consider changing `"%s%s%s%s" % (MessageTitle,"\n","\n", MessageLink)` to `"%s\n\n%s" % (MessageTitle, MessageLink)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of design patterns you can consider using. I will demonstrate a few where you don't need to use `[i]` even:

Accumulator:

```
messages = []
for feedItem in feed['items']:
    message = {'title':..., ...}
    message['link'] = ...  # alternative
    messages += [message]   # or messages.append(data)

print(messages)
```

Mapping (often the most elegant solution in simple cases like this):

```
def makeMessage(feedItem):
    message = {'title':..., ...}
    return message

messages = [makeMessage(fi) for fi in feed['items']]
print(messages)
```

Generators:

```
def makeMessages(feedItems):
    for item in feedItems:
        message = {'title':..., ...}
        yield message

messages = list( makeMessages(feed['items']) )
```

---

unrelated addendum:
You might even consider making a class for your messages:

```
class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, title, link, body):
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
        self.body = body

    def __str__(self):
        return ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```